# mat-radio-button, weird workflow

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with my code, but not able to:

```
          <mat-radio-group fxLayoutGap="6px" (change)="onChangeRadio($event.value)">
          <mat-radio-button
            color="primary"
            [value]="allowed"
            [checked]="true"
          > 
            {{ 'YES' | translate }}
          </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button
            color="primary"
            [value]="denied"
            [checked]="false"
          > 
            {{ 'NO' | translate }}
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

Both radio-button are checked.

Could you help me to find the problem?

Comment: try to give the same name for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove binding for value it works

```
   <mat-radio-group fxLayoutGap="6px" (change)="onChangeRadio($event.value)">
          <mat-radio-button
            color="primary"
            value="allowed"
            [checked]="true"
          > 
            <!-- {{ 'YES' | translate }} -->
          </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button
            color="primary"
            value="denied"
            [checked]="false"
          > 
            <!-- {{ 'NO' | translate }} -->
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

`````
````    <mat-radio-group fxLayoutGap="6px" (change)="onChangeRadio($event.value)">
          <mat-radio-button
            color="primary"
            value="allowed"
          > 
            {{ 'YES' | translate }}
          </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button
            color="primary"
            value="denied"
          > 
            {{ 'NO' | translate }}
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>````
`````

remove the check property if you were trying to fix it using this property .
Remove square brackets from value attribute since value which we are passing are not interpolated .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the checked attribute from each button. The checked state is controlled by the `value` input of the radiogroup, corresponding to the button `value` attribute.